# Solving system of four nonlinear equations

Tags: optimization, scipy

I am trying to solve a system of four non-linear equations using fsolve from `scipy.optimize` module. The Jacobian matrix (`fjac`) is filled with `nan`. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I've looked for similar questions and none of them were similar to my problem, which leads me to the conclusion that there is something fundamentally wrong in my attempts.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math

#Constants
Cn = 1.0
Cf = 0.8
Nn = 3.0
gamma = 1.4
R = 287.1 #J/kg*K
dn = 0.5 * 25.4 #mm
df = 2.1516 * 25.4 #mm
dv = 1.8553 * 25.4 #mm
dbt = 0.89 * 25.4 #mm
Tb = (40 + 273.15) #K
Pr = (13 + 1.01325) * 10 ** 5 #N/m2

guess_massflow = 0.3 # kg/s
guess_Pc = 12 * 10 ** 5 #N/m2
guess_Pb = 10 * 10 ** 5 #N/m2
guess_Ps = 14 * 10 ** 5 #N/m2

def f(p):

    massflow, Pb, Pc, Ps = p

    def pi_mod(d):
        return (math.pi * d ** 2) / 4 * 10 ** (-6)
    major_mod = Nn * Cn * Pb / (Tb ** 0.5)
    radical = (gamma + 1)/(gamma - 1)
    minor_mod = (gamma / R * (2 / (gamma + 1)) ** radical) ** 0.5

    radical2 = (gamma - 1) / gamma

    def main_mod(P1, P2):
        return P2 * (1/R/Tb * 2/radical2 * (P1/P2) ** (2/gamma) * (1 - (P1/P2) ** radical2)) ** 0.5

    f1 = massflow - major_mod * pi_mod(dn) * minor_mod
    f2 = massflow - Cf * pi_mod(df) * main_mod(Pb,Pc)
    f3 = massflow - Cf * pi_mod(dbt) * main_mod(Pc,Ps)
    f4 = massflow - Cf * pi_mod(dv) * main_mod(Ps,Pr)

    return (f1, f2, f3, f4)

solution = fsolve(f, (guess_massflow, guess_Pb, guess_Pc, guess_Ps), full_output = True)
```

Output:

```
(array([  3.00000000e-01,   1.10000000e+06,   1.10000000e+06,
     1.10000000e+06]), {'nfev': 19, 'fjac': array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
   [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]]), 'r': array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]), 'qtf': array([ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]), 'fvec': array([-0.65463805,  0.3       ,  0.3       , -3.45205928])}, 5, 'The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the \n  improvement from the last ten iterations.')
```

I have tried to solve this using Mathcad. Solution converged to, which is realistic:

```
[0.717255, 8.264713*10^5, 8.344225*10^5, 1.392793*10^6]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem comes from when the solver calls `main_mod(P1, P2)` with `P1>P2`, so I forced the function to return zero in this case... I don't know if it is physically correct... but it seems to work:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math

#Constants
Cn = 1.0
Cf = 0.8
Nn = 3.0
gamma = 1.4
R = 287.1 # J/kg/K  
dn = 0.5 * 25.4 # mm
df = 2.1516 * 25.4 # mm
dv = 1.8553 * 25.4 # mm
dbt = 0.89 * 25.4 # mm
Tb = (40 + 273.15) # K
Pr = (13 + 1.01325) * 1e5 # N/m2

def pi_mod(d):
    return (math.pi * d ** 2) / 4e6  # <- mm2 to m2?

radical = (gamma + 1)/(gamma - 1)
radical2 = (gamma - 1) / gamma
minor_mod = np.sqrt( gamma/R*( 2/(gamma + 1) )**radical )

def main_mod(P1, P2):
    if P1 < P2:
        return P2 * np.sqrt( 1/R/Tb * 2/radical2 * (P1/P2)**(2/gamma) * (1 - (P1/P2)**radical2) )
    else:
        return 0

def f(p):
    massflow, Pb, Pc, Ps = p

    major_mod = Nn*Cn/np.sqrt(Tb) * Pb 

    f1 = massflow - major_mod * pi_mod(dn) * minor_mod
    f2 = massflow - Cf * pi_mod(df) * main_mod(Pb, Pc)
    f3 = massflow - Cf * pi_mod(dbt) * main_mod(Pc, Ps)
    f4 = massflow - Cf * pi_mod(dv) * main_mod(Ps, Pr)

    return (f1, f2, f3, f4)

guess_massflow = 0.3 # kg/s
guess_Pc = 12e5 # N/m2
guess_Pb = 10e5 # N/m2
guess_Ps = 14e5 # N/m2

p_zero = (guess_massflow, guess_Pb, guess_Pc, guess_Ps)

solution = fsolve(f, p_zero, full_output=True)
```

I also changed the unit conversion in `pi_mod` (is it the area of a disk?) and I put the constant values and functions outside the `f` function